# request().body().asJson() as null

Tags: scala, playframework

Why do I always get request().body().asJson() value as null.

I am sending the form data as

```
clientId    test123
clientScopes    local
clientSecret    AfrTest123
clientSecretOnly    true
clientServices[]    test
clientVersions  []
module  clientConfig
save    Save
```

On the API side I am doing something like this.

```
    TestConfiguration config = Json.fromJson(request().body().asJson(), TestConfiguration.class);
```

Comment: Which version of Play are you using? Can you provide a small project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Maybe you are seeing this problem: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7682. Which was fixed at Play 2.6.9.